# javascript setInterval clear issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am facing one issue while using `setInterval` method.

When the jsp page is loaded at that time (onload), I have called one setInterval(function(),time) method. Following is the onload code of my jsp

```
var refreshLoop = 0;
var refreshFrequency = 900000;

$(window).load(function() {
    startRefresh();
}); 

function startRefresh() {
    refreshLoop = setInterval("refreshScreen()", refreshFrequency);
}
```

Now I have Drag and Drop functionality on this page which drag one row from div to another div. When I Drop my Row to another table that table got refresh. I had done ajax calling one drop happen to another div
Now What I want to do is when My drop id completed I want to clear this setInterval and make to default.

ex :  I have set my setInterval timings 10 min on page load so every time it will load the page after 10 mins . Now once I had drag and drop it will start counting 10 mins once I drop my row to another div.

I had done this in JavaScript and ajax.

Please suggests something on this issues.

Comment: Please, don't use code in `setInterval`. Instead, use `setInterval(refreshScreen, refreshFrequency)` and have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide.

Comment: where is the code for clearing the interval? did u try using window.clearInterval(refreshLoop) ?

Answer (score 1):

`window.clearInterval(refreshLoop)` whenever you wish to clear the interval.

Comment: Is it possible to use window.clearInterval(refreshLoop) when I got the ajax respose?
does it clear the interval?

Comment: yes, it is not related to the ajax response. refreshLoop holds the timer ID within it, which is get cleared when using window.clearInterval

Comment: Okies. In my case it wont happen.I tried to give it as window.clearInterval(refreshLoop) but it wont clear and my setInterval will run at specified time. what I need to look at for this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this code
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshLoop = '';
    var refreshFrequency = 900000;

    $(window).load(function() {
        startRefresh();
    });    

    function startRefresh() {
        if(refreshLoop){
            clearInterval(refreshLoop);
            refreshLoop = '';
        }
        refreshLoop = setInterval("refreshScreen()", refreshFrequency);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No need to set it to an empty string - you can just leave it as 0.  Also, it makes no difference if you `clearInterval` on an interval ID that doesn't exist, so no need for the if statement :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to clear the timer, use:

```
clearInterval(refreshLoop);
startRefresh();
```